# Spark History Server stuck loading

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

When I run **Spark History Server** I'm able to access the web interface at `http://<master IP address>:18080`. If I then run a Spark job and try to access `http://<master IP address>:18080/?showIncomplete=true` whilst the job is running, the screen hangs as per the screenshot below:

[image]

Once the job completes I am able to access `http://<master IP address>:18080/?showIncomplete=true` but no longer able to access `http://<master IP address>:18080/?showIncomplete=false`.

I am able to access `http://<master IP address>:18080/api/v1/applications` at all times.

Why might this be?

Comment: I know it's been almost 3 years for this question, but did you manage to solve it?
We had the same issue and it was something to do with the way entries are rendered on the UI.

Answer (score 0):

This usually is due to resource constraints on the spark history server. Try to increase memory (JAVA_HEAP, etc) and cpus by doubling. Also, make sure not to over allocate resources.